# Grails Spring Security won't allow compilation

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to run a local server for Grails using

```
grails run-app
```

This is for a legacy app that I need to work with so I don't know much details about it.

But I receive the following error:

```
| Compiling 73 source files.
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: grails/plugin/springsecurity/oauth/OAuthToken, method: super$1$implies signature: (Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I'm using

java version "1.7.0_55"
Grails version: 2.3.11

And Mac OS Yosemite

Comment: Does this error happen on newly created grails application?

Comment: Which version of the spring security plugin are you using?

Comment: @Ramsharan, no this is a legacy app

Comment: @JeffScottBrown how can I check the version?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown on the BuildConfig.groovy file I have compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC3"

Comment: But you're also using an OAuth plugin? There's no OAuth in core

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I also have compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-RC4'

Comment: What about migrating to `:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4`? I happened to work with this setup recently and it works like a charm. Is it an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very new to Grails, but as the comment of @MarcinŚwierczyński suggested I upgraded to RC4, and then everything worked.

Is strange though that I cloned the project again and I didn't had to upgrade the version. Might have been just a local temporal file that might had been causing the problem.